# View image with File Hash name Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

I wanna get image (image name) from File Hash column. So URL not show directly image name. This is my Controller:

```
public function viewImageD($filehash){
       $filename = DB::table('formd_image_detail')
        ->select('form_image')
        ->where('filehash', $filehash)
        ->get();
        $storagePath = (env('FORMD_IMAGE_URL') .$filename['form_image']);
        $result = Image::make($storagePath)->response();
        return $result;
}
```

I got error when this code is running.

```
[2018-12-19 06:20:59] local.INFO: [{"form_image":"imagedavid.png"}]  
[2018-12-19 06:21:00] local.ERROR: Undefined index: form_image
```

How the correct code of my controller? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: `$filename->form_image` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Please pass `env` variable in `config/app.php` file like:

**config/app.php**

```
'storage_path' => env('FORMD_IMAGE_URL', 'your path'),
```

**Your Controller**
use Config;

```
public function viewImageD($filehash){
       $filename = DB::table('formd_image_detail')
        ->select('form_image')
        ->where('filehash', $filehash)
        ->get();
        $storagePath = (Config::get('app.storage_path') .$filename['form_image']);
        $result = Image::make($storagePath)->response();
        return $result;
}
```